# Fresh Magento 2.4.3 Install only html rendered

Tags: magento2, localhost, frontend-error

So as the title states, after just installing Magento 2.4.3 using the following guide:

> https://www.simicart.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-localhost/

I was met with just the HTML render of the page, both on the frontend and admin panel.
I tried `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` as per someones instructions.
I have also tried removing the sample data and executing the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But those did not wield any result either.

As a note, I am very new to Magento (this being my first taste) so the solution might be fairly evident to some but maybe not to me.

Thank you for your help, have a great day!

Edit:

Here are some screenshots of what I mean:
[image]

[image]

I also changed all the folder and file permissions from read-only but still does not work.

Comment: have you checked the permissions of your files/directories?

Comment: What do you mean with "just the HTML render of the page"?

Comment: Can you please provide more screenshots ?

Comment: @BharathKumarJ I did edit to show some screenshots.

Comment: @RaulSanchez  I did edit to show some screenshots.

Comment: It seems static resources are giving 404... this could be caused by document root misconfiguration. Double check if it is configured pointing to /pub folder

Comment: @RaulSanchez how would I go about checking that and fixing it if it is such?

Comment: @LittleDTLe , i have posted the solution , please see below post of my solution.

Comment: @little check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, there is a solution:-

1. Please find the table core_config_data for this project.
2. Search for the path - "use_in_adminhtml" and make the value empty or NULL in MySQL.
3. Again search for the path - "use_in_frontend" and make the value empty or NULL in MySQL.
4. Run the deployment commands like "bin/magento s:up" and refresh the page.
5. Your issue will be solved.
6. If it is not solved , please post your queries again.

[image]

Thanks, and please let me know here if this solves.

Comment: When I run the SELECT query the table returns empty, so I tried to search for the path values manually but I cannot find the path values that way either. The only result I get in "path" that has "use" is "use_rewrites".

Comment: Also here is a screenshot of what I mean: https://prnt.sc/ul-q0oNzH3M2

Comment: Okay, here is another guess -
1. Please remove the static URL and media URL, I came to know from the link you have followed when installing the Magento , you can just make it as NULL or empty in mysql for the paths - 
base_static_url
base_static_url (secure)
base_media_url
base_media_url (secure)
After that try running the Magento deployment commands again (bin/magento s:up) is enough and make sure you are in developer mode.
Magento is not supported for windows and macOS , Please check this official link - 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: That did not seem to fix it either. I tried creating another setup which has the exact same problem, but it did not get fixed there either.

Comment: Then please try debugging , via various ways like:- from the browser dev tools , or you can choose to debug using the xdebug etc.All the best.Thanks